# Distribution of continuous distribution function of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose we have $X$ - random variable with distribution function $F(x)$, where $F(x)$ -- **continuous** distribution function. How to find the distribution function of new random variable $Y = F(X)$?

**Important** : There is no assumptions that $F(x)$ is strict monotone. So we can't just find inverse function $F^{-1}(x)$.

P.S. I know the answer: $U_{[0;1]}$, but how to prove it? I can prove it only in case, when $F(x)$ - strict monotone.

Comment: $P(Y\le t)=P(X\le F^{-1}(t))=t$ where $F^{-1}(t)=\min\{x:F(x)\ge t\}$.

Comment: @A.S. I agree with first $P(Y \leq t) = P(X \leq F^{-1}(t))$. But why $P(X \leq F^{-1}(t)) = t$ ?

Comment: Because $F(F^{-1}(t))=t$ by continuity of $F$.

Comment: @A.S. But how to prove that $F^{-1}(t)$ is inverse of $F(t)$?

Comment: @A.S. I can't understand how we made the definition of $F^{-1}(t)$. For example, can we define $F^{-1}(t) = \max\{x: F(x) \leq t\}$?

Comment: By definition of $F^{-1}$, $F(F^{-1}(t))\ge t$. By continuity of $F$, $F(F^{-1}(t))< t+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. // No, you can't define that *in general* because such a $\max$ will not exist for discontinuous $F$. My definition offers a "pseudo"-inverse for discontinuous $F$ as well.

Comment: @A.S. I'm sorry for my stupid question, but, in fact, I can't understand. $F(t)$ is continuous function, right? So, in our case we can define $max$, why not?

Comment: @A.S. Oh, I understood! Thanks, really! Can you recommend some books, which cover this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u\in\left(0,1\right)$.

If $z_{u}:=\inf\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid F\left(x\right)\geq u\right\} $
then $F\left(z_{u}\right)\geq u$ since $F$ is right-continuous.

So we have $F(x)<u\iff x<z_{u}$.

If moreover $F$ is continuous then $P\left(X<z_{u}\right)=F\left(z_{u}\right)=u$.

Then $P\left(F\left(X\right)<u\right)=P\left(X<z_{u}\right)=u$.